# Calling Redmine REST API to Get All Issues: 406 Error?

Tags: ruby, redmine

I've setup a Redmine server for a project I'm working on here with the REST API enabled: http://zqwjs.se.rit.edu/redmine. However, when I went to test if the issues.xml file is showing up on my redmine server (http://zqwjs.se.rit.edu/redmine/issues.xml), I'll end up getting a blank page. Does anyone have any suggestions on how I should fix my redmine configuration to allow me to call the REST API without errors?

Note: If I ran the following ruby code against my redmine server, I'll get a 406 error back:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'active_resource'

# Issue model on the client side
class Issue < ActiveResource::Base
   self.site = 'http://zqwjs.se.rit.edu/redmine/'
end

# Retrieving issues
issues = Issue.find(:all)
print issues
```

Printout from console:

```
NOTE: Gem::Specification#default_executable= is deprecated with no replacement.
It will be removed on or after 2011-10-01.
Gem::Specification#default_executable= called from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/
specifications/rubygems-update-1.8.2.gemspec:11.
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activeresource-3.0.9/lib/active_resource/conne
ction.rb:145:in `handle_response': Failed.  Response code = 406.  Response messa
ge = Not Acceptable. (ActiveResource::ClientError)
        from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activeresource-3.0.9/lib/active_r
esource/connection.rb:114:in `request'
        from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activeresource-3.0.9/lib/active_r
esource/connection.rb:79:in `get'
        from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activeresource-3.0.9/lib/active_r
esource/connection.rb:217:in `with_auth'
        from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activeresource-3.0.9/lib/active_r
esource/connection.rb:79:in `get'
        from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activeresource-3.0.9/lib/active_r
esource/base.rb:857:in `find_every'
        from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activeresource-3.0.9/lib/active_r
esource/base.rb:777:in `find'
        from redmine-interact.rb:10
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have this problem with version 1.2.1. Your exact code works fine on my installation, so I assume that you are running an older version of Redmine that has not built in the Issues REST API yet.

Comment: Just checked my installation: I'm running 1.2.0 on the server. I think the REST API support for issues was added in 1.0, so I don't think this issue has to do with the version of Redmine I'm running.

Comment: In that case, my best guess is that you haven't restarted the server since enabling the REST API? I noticed that all the other XMLs like http://zqwjs.se.rit.edu/redmine/projects.xml are also not working. Other than that, I am out of ideas here. This is the point where I would start checking error logs and digging into the source and adding `printf` output to the issues controller. Can you run the app in development mode with Webrick to be able to see exceptions?

Comment: Just realized I misread the version, turns out the installation being ran is 0.9.3, which explains why the REST API isn't working. Thanks for the help!